# Paypal sandbox, nothing works

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I can login to developer.paypal.com

After that, nothing works today.

Can't login to sandbox.paypal
Can't create trial accounts
Can't edit existing trial accounts

Everything was working fine last week. Now nothing works.

Tried clearing cache and deleting cookies.
Tried a different browser.

I'm 1000% sure something is wrong with paypal today .... what should I do?

Comment: They seem to delight in torturing developers. They had a major fiasco in March which resulted in us pulling all our PayPal buttons off our website. Enough is enough. There are other solutions.

Comment: I've had hiccups with the Sandbox recently, but things seem to be working fine for me now. Are you still having trouble?